# Mobile video player in Chrome doesn't work on certain site

Tags: chrome-for-android, video, bugs

I have a problem with build-in video player in Chrome.
For such sites, as  m.youtube.com  it's work correctly and looks like this:

[image: Normal player]

It worked for site yummyanime.club as too.
But some days ago video player suddenly stopped working on this site in Chrome and other browsers. Instead, the video is played in the same player as on the computer (although I use a mobile version of the site). It looks like this:

[image]

Player stopped working only on this site.

It is inconvenient player on my phone. I want to use a player like in the first screenshot. I was surprised when I opened this site on my other old phone, and there this mobile player works:
[image]

In short, the problem is this: the mobile video player suddenly stopped working on a certain site on my new phone. This is a problem for all browsers. But on my old phone, everything works fine.

About system in old(correctly work) and new phone(have bug) accordingly:
[image]

So, main question is how to fix this problem and enable mobile video player on my new phone? But I will be grateful for any information about this: how this mobile player work, does it have any settings, related links and so on.